# Find if a time falls on a rising or falling tide

Tags: r

I have this dataframe:

```
tides <- data.frame("time"= c("08:35", "14:28", "13:10", "13:25", "14:30", "12:20"),
                    "tide 1"= c("04:18 H", "03:54 L", "03:36 H", "02:00 L", "03:54 H", "05:54 H"),
                    "tide 2"= c("10:30 L", "10:30 H", "09:48 L", "08:18 H", "10:06 L", "12:06 L"),
                    "tide 3"= c("16:42 H", "16:36 L", "16:00 H", "14:24 L", "16:12 H", "18:12 H"),
                    "tide 4"= c("22:48 L", "23:00 H", "22:06 L", "20:36 H", "22:24 L", "00:30 L"),              
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)



 time  tide.1  tide.2  tide.3  tide.4
1 08:35 04:18 H 10:30 L 16:42 H 22:48 L
2 14:28 03:54 L 10:30 H 16:36 L 23:00 H
3 13:10 03:36 H 09:48 L 16:00 H 22:06 L
4 13:25 02:00 L 08:18 H 14:24 L 20:36 H
5 14:30 03:54 H 10:06 L 16:12 H 22:24 L
6 12:20 05:54 H 12:06 L 18:12 H 00:30 L
```

I need to work out if the times in `time` column fall on a rising or falling tide. The `tide` columns give the time of low and high tides on that particular day.

l = low tide, h = high tide.

Is there an efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Please show us what you have done.

Comment: What I've done so far is messy, complicated and didn't get me any near to a solution. If I post my history it will make the question dense and untractable.

Comment: I sympathize. My first efforts got overly complex, too. I left them in for the amusement of all.

Comment: I think closing this question is entirely too stringent. Most of the questions on SO fail to explain what searches have been done and many of them don't even measure up to this one on the scale of having a reproducible dataset. This question at least posed a question that was both clear and had code-delivered data. If we are going to close this question then we will need to close about 50% of the questions I see coming in. Lighten up on the close votes a little bit, folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided having both a POSIXct/numeric dataframe and a character dataframe was too complex and decided to do the conversion inside an `apply`-ed function of the original characters.

```
apply (tides, 1, function(chars) { 
      tms <- as.POSIXct(chars, format="%H:%M") # will be the current day
      if( tms[5] < tms[4]){ tms[5] <- 
                as.POSIXct( 24*60*60 + as.numeric( tms[5]) , origin="1970-01-01")
                           } # add a day if last time after midnight
       column <- findInterval( as.numeric(tms[1]), as.numeric(tms[2:5])  )  
       # offset of 1 needed since columns 2:5 are max/min  
       # pull H/L designation from correct column
       previous_tide <- substr(chars[column+1], 7,7) }
    )
[1] "H" "H" "L" "H" "L" "L"
```

So if the previous tide was "H", it's a "falling tide" and *vice-versa*. Seems to check out correctly.

```
#------ earlier  work---
```

First I needed to increment the time for the tides at the end of the cycle that were in the next day (after converting to a time class.)

```
tides2 <- data.frame( lapply(tides, as.POSIXct, format="%H:%M") )
tides2[ tides2[ ,5] < tides2[,4] , 5] <- as.POSIXct(24*60*60 + # day in seconds
        as.numeric(tides2[ tides2[ ,5] < tides2[,4] , 5]) , origin="1970-01-01")
```

Then I thrashed around before realizing that `apply` screws up even `POSIXct` dates but that using data.matrix converts neatly to numeric:

```
apply(data.matrix(tides2), 1, function(x) 
                      findInterval( x[1], x[2:5]) )
[1] 1 2 2 2 2 2
```

So most of your `time[,1]`'s are in the second period. At first I assumed, incorrectly, that these would all be in the same group, but I see I don't think of tide tables correctly. (Kind of embarrassing since I do some sailing.) So you need a lookup:

```
apply( tides[2:5], 1, substr, 7,7)
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
tide.1 "H"  "L"  "H"  "L"  "H"  "H" 
tide.2 "L"  "H"  "L"  "H"  "L"  "L" 
tide.3 "H"  "L"  "H"  "L"  "H"  "H" 
tide.4 "L"  "H"  "L"  "H"  "L"  "L"
```

Ya' know this is getting way too complicated. I'm going to redo this from the very beginning.